# DataFrame create column and groupby from str.contain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example:

Given a pd.DataFrame similar to :

```
In [37]: df_ex
Out[37]:
           value
AS1_TEMP      12
AS1_TENS     190
AS1_SPEED   2000
AS2_TEMP      24
AS2_TENS     200
AS2_SPEED   1750
AS3_TEMP      11
AS3_TENS     187
AS3_SPEED   1621
```

I want a final df with new index/columns like:

```
     TEMP  TENS  SPEED
AS1  12    190   2000
AS2  24    200   1750
AS3  11    187   1621
```

The values are always different but the tags are always the same, for the "rigs" and for the "property".

I don't know where to start looking info relative to my problem. Since I want a completely new index and columns, I suposse I should begin creating a couple of series with them.

Next step is where I'm lost. Even if I could create a blank dataframe with these two series and start populating with a loop, I'm sure there is something hidden inside pandas able to perform this without iterate all the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the index, and expand to True - this converts the index to a multiIndex; from there, you [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to get your output

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df.index = df.index.str.split("_",expand=True)

df.unstack().droplevel(0,axis=1)

                  value
       SPEED    TEMP    TENS
AS1     2000    12      190
AS2     1750    24      200
AS3     1621    11      187
```

Comment: Or in one line: `df.set_index(df.index.str.split('_', expand=True)).unstack()`.

Comment: Pandas docs has some great examples. Once in a while, I look at the source code, to get an idea of what’s going on. Helpful too